# Saving nested enum to db using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, enums

For example, we have a Shops table. Each shop belongs to some country (for now implemented as ENUM). Now I need to map the shop not only to a country, but also to a region of that country.

First idea was to make separate table Country and Region. Country hasMany regions, Shop belongs to one region and through it to Country. But what if I need to be able to map Shop to a Country without specifying the region of it? With my solution it is impossible.

Second idea was to use complex ENUM. Like this:

```
public enum Location implements ContainsRegion {

FRANCE("France") {
    public EnumSet getRegions() {
        return EnumSet.allOf(FranceRegions.class);
    }
},
GERMANY("Germany") {
    public EnumSet getRegions() {
        return EnumSet.allOF(GermanyRegions.class);
    }
};

private final String country;

private Region region;

public static Location factory(String name) throws IOException {
    for(Location c : values()) {
        if(c.country.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    throw new IOException("Unknown country");
}

@JsonCreator
public static Location factory(@JsonProperty("region") Region region, @JsonProperty("name") String name) throws IOException {
    Location location = factory(name);
    if(isNull(region)) {
        return location;
    }
    if(location.getRegions().contains(region)) {
        location.setRegion(region);
        return location;
    }
    throw new IOException("This region is not available for location");
}

}
```

It works ok with JSON serialization and deserialization, but I can't map this to db table? Is there any solution for this?

The last idea is to make a separate entity Location:
it will contain the reference to Shop, Country and Region. And will be mapped to Shop as @OneToOne. In this case it from Shop entity through Location entity I'll be able to get/set country and region, and if region is not specified it could be just null.

Please, tell me, what is the best approach to complete this task?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible and you should think twice when using enums with JPA.

Please read my article about that topic:
https://martinelli.ch/2018/01/08/mapping-enums-with-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

currently JPA 2.1 doesn't support mapping enum contained variables.
I think the first solution is correct, make a ManyToOne relation of Region inside Shop and a oneToOne relation between Region and country, (hence the country will be Eagerly loaded with the Region and you can access it any time) , you can also provide a convenience method inside the Region to provide the name of the country + the region or whatever is convenient with your business